# Sorted list of random repeated numbers to sorted list of repeated and continuos numbers in google sheets

Tags: list, google-sheets, numbers

I think the best way to show the problem is with an example. Column A is what i have now, and column B is what I would want.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 14 | 6 |
| 14 | 6 |
| 17 | 7 |
| 17 | 7 |
| 17 | 7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Based on your comment, use this formula

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A), VLOOKUP(A1:A, {UNIQUE(A1:A), ArrayFormula(RANK(UNIQUE(A1:A), UNIQUE(A1:A), 1))}, 2, 0), ""))`

[image]

Previous answer: Have you already used the `SORT` formula?

Try `=SORT(A1:A, 1, 1)` in cell `B1`

Comment: It is not quite what I am looking for. i already have the numbers in row A sorted, so there is no number 3 or 4, in the example. I would like to generate column B, from A. This would be like a sorted list with continuos natural numbers, but they should repeat in case they repeat in A column

Comment: That does seem to do the trick!! Thanks a lot

Comment: If it worked fine for you, could you also accept the answer? Thanks

Comment: Broly, nice solution. Keep in mind that you don't need to repeat ArrayFormula. And since every entry in A:A is numeric, you also don't need to test if it's a number with ISNUMBER. A shortened version of your formula: =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A, {UNIQUE(A:A), RANK(UNIQUE(A:A), UNIQUE(A:A), 1)}, 2, 0)))

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts at row 2 through row 10 column A. In B2 :

```
=arrayformula(1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10))
```

in C2

```
=sumproduct(($B$1:$B1)*($A$1:$A1<A2))+1
```

[image]